# How to infer type argument of ? extends Class in interface declaration

Tags: java, generics

I am developing some interfaces for a game and I came to the following interface definitions so far:

- `public interface Player<A extends Action, R extends Result> { }`
- `public interface Game<P extends Player<? extends Action, ? extends Result>> { }`

However now I would like to access the `? extends Result` in the `Game` interface, I know I could do it by adding three generic types to `Game`, but that should not be needed as the information is already there.

I would want something like the following:

`public interface <A, R> Game<P extends Player<A extends Action, R extends Result>> { }`

This code however is not legal in Java (Java 8) as I cannot define `<A, R>` like this.

How do I do it?

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Are you modifying the `Game` interface? If so, you just don't have the `<A,R>` in front of the interface name; that's only used for methods with their own generic parameters.

Comment: @chrylis I am trying to find a suitable `Game` interface that captures the already information correctly from `Player`. I need the `<A, R>` types for later use in the methods.

Comment: You already know the way - declare 3 generic types. I don't see any other possible way.

Comment: But you don't put `<A,R>` *there*. It's already present in the generic definition that comes after `Game`. And you're still not making much sense; you're talking like `Player` and `Game` are already pre-existing interfaces, but you're also talking like you are modifying them. Are you just asking for the generic definition you'll need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to do as you initially suggest, to add "three generic types to `Game`".

As long as you create the proper bounds when the generic type parameters are declared, you can use them to define another type parameter.

That is the best way to get `A` and `R` available in your interface's methods.

```
interface Game<A extends Action, R extends Result, P extends Player<A, R>> { }
```